# how create custom effect of an image on existing image in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I want create a custom effect as a like on heart, square,etc shapes these are png files on the image how should I do that?

And I want create this inside a Dialog box.

I tried stack widgets, chipRRect widgets to create this type of effect but none of them really worked.

```
 late File _imageFile;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _imageFile = widget.imageFile;
  }

  Future<void> _cropImage() async {
    CroppedFile? croppedFile = await ImageCropper()
        .cropImage(sourcePath: _imageFile.path, aspectRatioPresets: [
      CropAspectRatioPreset.square,
      CropAspectRatioPreset.ratio3x2,
      CropAspectRatioPreset.original,
      CropAspectRatioPreset.ratio4x3,
      CropAspectRatioPreset.ratio16x9
    ], uiSettings: [
      AndroidUiSettings(
          toolbarTitle: 'Crop',
          cropGridColor: Colors.black,
          initAspectRatio: CropAspectRatioPreset.original,
          lockAspectRatio: false),
      IOSUiSettings(title: 'Crop')
    ]);

    if (croppedFile != null) {
      setState(() {
        _imageFile = File(croppedFile.path);
      });

      // Get.to(() => AddImageScreen(
      //     imageFile: File(_imageFile.path), imagePath: _imageFile.path));
      showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (BuildContext context) {
          return AlertDialog(
            title: Text('Uploaded Image'),
            content: SingleChildScrollView(
              child: ListBody(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Image.file(_imageFile),
                  Text('Original'),
                  // Add other options here
                ],
              ),
            ),
            actions: <Widget>[
              TextButton(
                child: Text('Use this image'),
                onPressed: () {
                  // Implement your function to use this image
                  Navigator.of(context).pop();
                  Get.to(() => AddImageScreen());
                },
              ),
            ],
          );
        },
      );
    }
    ;
  }
```